# Add to cart Servlet - how it works

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,com.stakoverflow.bookstore.servlets.*"%>
<html>
<body>
<center><br><br>
<h1>Book Store</h1>
<table>
<%
List books=new ArrayList();
Book book=new Book();
book.setBid(101);
book.setBname("Learn java");
book.setAuthor("dsouza");
book.setCost(99.99);
book.setCat("Java");
book.setPub("india");
book.setIsbn("11-11");
books.add(book);

book= new Book();
book.setBid(102);
book.setBname("Learn JDBC");
book.setAuthor("bsk");
book.setCost(99.99);
book.setCat("Java");
book.setPub("india-pub");
book.setIsbn("11-11");
books.add(book);


book=new Book();
book.setBid(103);
book.setBname("Learn JSP");
book.setAuthor("pintu");
book.setCost(99.99);
book.setCat("Java");
book.setPub("newage");
book.setIsbn("11-11");
books.add(book);

book=new Book();
book.setBid(104);
book.setBname("Learn EJB");
book.setAuthor("Rj");
book.setCost(99.99);
book.setCat("Java");
book.setPub("tmh");
book.setIsbn("11-11");
books.add(book);

out.println("<table>");
%>
<tr>
<td>Book ID</td>
<td>Book Name</td>
<td>Author</td>
<td>Cost</td>
<td>Cat</td>
<td>Pub</td>
<td>ISBN</td>
</tr>
<% 
Iterator it=books.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    book=(Book)it.next();
%>
<tr>
<td><%=book.getBid()%></td>
<td><%=book.getBname()%></td>
<td><%=book.getAuthor()%></td>
<td><%=book.getCost()%></td>
<td><%=book.getCat()%></td>
<td><%=book.getPub()%></td>
<td><%=book.getIsbn()%></td>

**<td>
*<form action="addcart.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="bname" value="<%=book.getBname() %>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>*
</form>**
</td>
</tr>
<%
}
out.println("</table>");
%>
<a href="placeorder.jsp">Place My Order</a>
<form action="/Lab8/showcart.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="Show My Cart"/>
</form>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

for the above jsp code, 
i am creating an ArrayList object books and adding Book object to the array list

"/>
    *

when we click the add to cart button, how does value="<%=book.getBname() %> picks the corresponding book value for different books,

it should send same bookname always as per my understanding,

Comment: You have multiple Books.

Comment: Why are you resetting the "book" variable with new values ?? You can use book1, book2,book3 right ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click the corresponding 'Add to cart' button next to the book, the form which the book is in is submitted to the `addcart.jsp` . In this jsp, you should be getting the book name using `request.getParameter("bname")` which is the hidden field containing the book name (this is submited using the form).

Thats how it works

Comment: if you find this answer usefull you can upvote it and accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over books,it creates n forms assuming there are n books.
In each form,you are keeping a hidden field containing bookname.So once you click on `"Add to Cart"` button,only that form data is submitted to the `addcart.jsp` where you can access the bookname using `request.getParameter("bname")`.

Just an example to make things more clear

**any.jsp**

```
  ....
        <body>
              <%for(int i=1;i<5;i++){ %>
              <form method ="get" action="myServlet">
              <input type="hidden" name="bname" value="<%=i %>"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
               </form>
               <%} %>
          </body>

....
```

if you see source code of this page,it is

```
....
<body>

      <form method ="get" action="myServlet">
      <input type="hidden" name="bname" value="1"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
       </form>

      <form method ="get" action="myServlet">
      <input type="hidden" name="bname" value="2"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
       </form>

      <form method ="get" action="myServlet">
      <input type="hidden" name="bname" value="3"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
       </form>

      <form method ="get" action="myServlet">
      <input type="hidden" name="bname" value="4"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
       </form>

  </body>
  ...
```

I hope you get the idea how it works.